# How to manage the position of intertext within align

Tags: spacing, align, amsmath

```
\begin{equation*} 
\begin{aligned}
E(X) & = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}x\frac{e^{ - \lambda }\lambda ^x}{x!} \\
     & = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ - \lambda }\lambda ^x }{(x-1)!} \\
     & = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ - \lambda } \lambda ^x }{(x-1)!} \\
     & = \lambda \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ - \lambda } \lambda ^{(x-1)} }{(x-1)!} \\
    \shortintertext{Now, let us substitute x-1 by y, then}
E(X) & = \lambda \sum_{y=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ - \lambda } \lambda^y }{y!} \\
     & = \lambda
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

My code and the result displayed are as above, how can I move that intertext to the left? Also, how can I reduce the space before the aligned part? I'm using packages `amsmath` and `mathtools`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write your equation an quite complicated way. Tray:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[active,displaymath,tightpage]{preview}% for show only tcolorbox
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
\begin{align*}
E(X) & = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}x\frac{e^{ - \lambda }\lambda ^x}{x!} \\
     & = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ - \lambda }\lambda ^x }{(x-1)!} \\
     & = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ - \lambda } \lambda ^x }{(x-1)!} \\
     & = \lambda \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ - \lambda } \lambda ^{(x-1)} }{(x-1)!} 
    \shortintertext{Now, let us substitute $x-1$ by $y$, then}
E(X) & = \lambda \sum_{y=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ - \lambda } \lambda^y }{y!} \\
     & = \lambda
\end{align*}
    \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

The cause of your problem seems to be `equation*` environment which doesn't allow to use `\intertext` or `shortintertext` in it.

Comment: @AudreyFeng, glad to hear this! Than you can accept answer (by tick on the check mark at the top left of answer ...) :-)